# Is there a way to benchmark a Java program's startup?

Tags: java

Out of curiosity, is there a way to benchmark a Java program's startup? You know, the time it takes from the moment you click its icon to the moment it finally runs the main method?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a batch job that grabs the system time, then starts your Java program.  In the first line of your Java program, you can then grab the system time again.  That should give you a pretty close measure of your startup time.